# How to increase the performance of mass indexer in Hibernate Search

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am running FullTextEntityManager.createIndexer() to create indexes in elasticsearch on a table that has around 400000 records.

The time taken is really not acceptable. After searching in the internet I tried increasing the heap size (min 1g and max 6g), set the number of open file descriptors to 64000, still no good improvements. I have pasted down the measurements for different values for configuring the indexer:

```
Threads Batch Time    ESmin  ESmax
10       30     7min
10       100    5min
10       1000   5min
20       100    4min
20       1000   9min
5        500    6min
20       500    4min    1g    6g 
10       500    4min    1g    6g  
5        1000   6min    1g    6g
10       1000   5min    1g    6g
```

This was just a poc, the production data has a billion records. Could someone please give me some inputs on what can be done to increase the performance to an acceptable level.

Please note that on hibernate I am using cp30 connection pooling, with the settings as shown below:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What version of Hibernate Search are you using?

Comment: hibernate-entitymanager 5.0.6.Final ; hibernate-search-orm - 5.6.0.Beta1; hibernate-core 5.0.6.Final; hibernate-search-engine 5.6.0.Beta1; lucene-core 5.4.1;

Comment: Ok, so you are on the latest HSEARCH, that's good. We haven't spend overly much time yet with performance optimizing the new Elasticsearch index manager and its integration into the mass indexing framework. You can expect improvements in the upcoming Beta/CR/Final releases of 5.6. But if you could perform your own profiling and share any insights you may gain, that'd be appreciated very much.

Comment: Actually - I can run a matchAll query after 5 mins for starting the indexer, in the soap UI and see the results being fetched there; but the indexer.startAndWait() just doesnt terminate, I am not sure what else it does. I read about index segments being merged and so on, is this what causes the startAndWait() to hang?

Comment: Hum, that's interesting. With the Elasticsearch backends we just send indexing requests to the server, if you indeed can see *all* results after a given time, there is no reason for the mass indexer to hang. Maybe it's some bug in there which prevents it from shutting down. Any chance you debug your test and see where it's hanging?

Comment: I was wondering if dynamic sharding could be somehow utilized to improve mass indexer. Shards are based on a certain certeria like ( book entities are indexed into shards based on their publishing date, for example.) Mass indexer already executes threads in parallel, in a normal scenario they all work with the same index(I know Lucene has this concept of segments- i donno if this somehow reduces the contention of threads for accessing this single index).

Comment: But with dynamic sharding could we further increase parallelism - in this case because there are going to be many different indexes getting created, we could have a set of threads working on a shard, while other sets work parallely on other shard - that way increasing cpu utilization(In the normal scenario I noticed that CPU was not getting utilised fully) - Just a thought!!!.